# Range Slider Drag Center of Values Vue

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I am looking for a way to make the center of the range slider draggable so that I can move it by pressing on the center from side to side.
What I need is support for dragging both controllers; by clicking and dragging between the controllers, both controllers move together. The behavior of this component is to place the controller closest to the clicked position, and I can't find any way to change this from any property.

[image]

and there is also a way to add between both inputs this input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
background: #500000;
}
to create your track in css

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({

    data() {
        return {
            min: 0,
            max: 360,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        adjust_min() {
            this.min = Math.min(this.min, this.max)
            this.$emit('fromSlider', Math.trunc(this.min))
        },
        adjust_max() {
            this.max = Math.max(this.min, this.max)
            this.$emit('toSlider', Math.trunc(this.max))
        },

    },

})
```

```css
.sliders_control {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 50px;
}

.form_control {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #635a5a;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    pointer-events: all;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #C6C6C6;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
    appearance: none;
    pointer-events: all;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #C6C6C6;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb:hover {
    background: #f7f7f7;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb:active {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #387bbe, 0 0 9px #387bbe;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #387bbe, 0 0 9px #387bbe;
}


input[type="range"] {
    //   -webkit-appearance: none; 
    appearance: none;
    height: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #C6C6C6;
    pointer-events: none;
}

#fromSlider {
    height: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
    <div class="sliders_control">
        <input id="fromSlider" class="fromSlider" type="range" v-model.number="min" min="0" max="360" step="1"
            @input="adjust_min" />
        <input id="toSlider" class="toSlider" type="range" v-model.number="max" min="0" max="360" step="1"
            @input="adjust_max" />
    </div>
```

[image: Slider test]